# How to calculate years and months between more than two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'work_experience' storing the experience details of candidate.

[Screen shot for work_experience table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzmKb.png)

`from` and `to` columns stores the experience of a user in a company. They are date fields.

I want to get total experience of a user in years and months.

My tries are:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 'from', 'to')) AS years,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 'from', 'to')) % 12 AS months
FROM
    work_experience
WHERE
    'userid' = 15;
```

OUTPUT: 1 years 7 months

Actually the result has to be 2years 7 months.
How can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.:)

SELECT 
FLOOR(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`from`,`to`))/12) AS years,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`from`,`to`))%12 AS months 
FROM `work_experience` WHERE `userid`=15.

Thanks to all...